# Calculate and merge vector output with scalar input using purrr or plyr in R

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, purrr

I have the following code calculate output from scalar input and merge the results into a data frame together with the input. I tried to do the same thing with purrr and plyr, but got stuck. Can anyone provide some equivalent code?

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

sigma = rep(2,5)

sim_ar1 = function(b1,sigma) b1 + sigma

data.table(b1 = seq(0.9,1,0.03)) %>% 
  .[,
    data.frame(sigma, sim1 = sim_ar1(b1,sigma)), 
    by = b1]
```

Comment: Fyi, using `data.frame(...)` there can be very slow https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Do%27s-and-Don%27ts#4-dont-coerce-j-to-list-use-list-directly More standard code would be `data.table(b1 = seq(0.9,1,0.03))[, .(sigma = sigma, sim1 = sim_ar1(b1, sigma)), by=b1]`

Comment: @Frank, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tidyverse`. The key is to use `expand.grid` to create all the combination between `b1` and `sigma`, and then use `map2` to apply the `sim_ar1` function to create the `sim1` column. `dt` should look like the same as your example output from `data.table`.

```
library(tidyverse)

sigma <- rep(2,5)
b1 <- seq(0.9,1,0.03)
sim_ar1 <- function(b1,sigma) b1 + sigma

dt <- expand.grid(b1 = b1, sigma = sigma) %>%
  arrange(b1) %>%
  mutate(sim1 = map2(b1, sigma, sim_ar1))

dt
     b1 sigma sim1
1  0.90     2  2.9
2  0.90     2  2.9
3  0.90     2  2.9
4  0.90     2  2.9
5  0.90     2  2.9
6  0.93     2 2.93
7  0.93     2 2.93
8  0.93     2 2.93
9  0.93     2 2.93
10 0.93     2 2.93
11 0.96     2 2.96
12 0.96     2 2.96
13 0.96     2 2.96
14 0.96     2 2.96
15 0.96     2 2.96
16 0.99     2 2.99
17 0.99     2 2.99
18 0.99     2 2.99
19 0.99     2 2.99
20 0.99     2 2.99
```

#### Update

In fact, since `sim_ar1` is vectorized, there is no need to use `map2` from `purrr`. `dplyr` alone is sufficient.

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- expand.grid(data_frame(b1 = b1, sigma = 2)) %>%
  arrange(b1) %>%
  mutate(sim1 = sim_ar1(b1, sigma))
```

Comment: You may also check the `expand` and `complete`

Comment: sim_ar1 is vectorized, so why is map2 being used here?

Comment: @Frank You are right. I was trying to fit in the use of `purrr`, but it seems like `dplyr` alone is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I did learn the usage of expand.grid from you. I also posted an answer and you may check it out~

Answer (score 1):

I also develop an answer using map with bind_rows and would like to share here

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

sigma = rep(2,5)

sim_ar1 = function(b1,sigma) b1 + sigma

map(b1, ~data.frame(b1 = .x, results = sim_ar1(.x,sigma))) %>%  bind_rows()
```

As is suggested by @ycw, using map_df could make the come more concise and the last line would be:

```
map_df(b1, ~data.frame(b1 = .x, results = sim_ar1(.x,sigma)))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution. You can also do `map_df(b1, ~data.frame(b1 = .x, results = sim_ar1(.x,sigma)))`. By doing this, you can remove `%>%  bind_rows()` to make the code more concise.

Comment: @ycw, thanks for your comments and I'll update my answer.